# 55 mins OSL-AMS-UK enough?

Tags: schengen, airport-transfer, amsterdam, ams, klm

I am flying from OSL-AMS-BRS and have 55mins however the gate closes 15 mins before so that’s 40mins I think. When we touch down in AMS I assume we need a bus to get to the gate? More time.

I then assume I have to go through passport control. Do I have to queue up or can I go through a hopefully quicker passport e-gate.

Do you think I have enough time. This was all booked via KLM. Hand luggage only. Thanks

**UPDATE** : Made it through but luckily showed the passport control guard my boarding time and he sent me to the front of the queue. I think I would have made it as the queue was relatively short however it was getting bigger. As someone suggested hopefully the guards would have let those with short connections through too. If anyone can find a stress free way of travel the please let me know!!

Comment: Don't worry too much about buses at AMS. Back in 2016 I connected in AMS outbound and inbound. Outbound, my plane from STR was assigned Gate B34 with a jetbridge, and I had to go to D4 for the bus to my connecting flight. Inbound, same thing, bus to D4, walk to B32. I was too stressed to check my watch (tight connections), but taking a bus didn't feel longer than walking the length of terminal B.

Comment: You will have to go through exit passport control since you are exiting the Schengen Area, but that should be pretty quick, more so if you have an EU or EEA passport, probably even quicker if you can use e-gates. What are the flight numbers and what date is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do you think I have enough time.

KLM thinks it's enough time, otherwise they wouldn't have sold you the ticket. A connection is never guaranteed but you have a very good chance of making it. If you don't KLM is fully responsible and will rebook you on the next available flight and may have to pay you delay compensation. Since KLM doesn't want to do that, they set the minimum connection times for a very high success rate. Amsterdam is their home base, so they have lots and lots of data to make these calls.

Comment: This is a theoretical answer which doesn't mesh with the 2022 reality. Careful there. The MCTs have not been updated in GDS for the post-COVID madness travel has become.

Comment: @chx unless this falls on a major holiday I expect (or hope?) things have gotten better since the chaos of this summer, haven’t they?

Comment: @chx: I have done a fair bit of flying in 2022 and haven't missed a single connection so far (Europe, US, South America mostly). Maybe I just got lucky but by and large things went fairly smoothly and not nearly as chaotic as the media portraits it.

Answer (score 8):

I have connected from UK to Schengen and back at Schiphol quite often, including several connections in the 50min-1h range. I never missed a connection, nor came dangerously close to it.

The terminal buildings are rather compact, and getting around doesn't take long (provided you can walk briskly). If you are collecting from your plane by bus this shouldn't add much to your connection time.

You will need to pass through passport control. There are e-gates, but I've very rarely if ever seen them in use. If there is a long queue at passport control, they will open a fast lane for imminent departures.

While the 55min should be enough, a delayed departure from Oslo could easily get you into trouble. I had a flighs departing late for Schiphol because of bad weather in Amsterdam, leading to a 90min delay of my arrival there. That was on a flight with 5h connection time, but it could just as easily have happened on another one. Provided that you make your best effort to reach the departure gate on time, if you end up missing your connection, it will be up to KLM to provide you with accommodation and a seat on their next available flight to your destination. As Schiphol is full of KLM staff, it should be easy enough to make that happen.

In your shoes I would be unconcerned about the connection, UNLESS it is vital that I arrive at Bristol on the expected date. In that case, just flying a day earlier might be the fix.